How to Prevent API Call in Sitecore Search Until User Submits Search in Next.js (Sitecore JSS)?
I'm working with Sitecore-Search and Next.js (Sitecore JSS) to create a search component. Right now, I don’t want the search API to be called when the page loads. I only want the API call to happen when the user types a search term and either presses Enter or clicks the submit button.
In other words, I want to trigger the API call only after the user submits their search, not on page load or at initial level when we define Search parameters. I can hide the results using a state logic from the frontend code, but I also want to prevent unnecessary API calls for better performance.
I tried some ways from the documentation like these:
 query: (query) => {
  // query.getRequest();
},


query: (query) => {
  return false
},


query: (query) => {
   if(isUserClickedOnSubmit) {
     query.getRequest();
   }
},

But none of these are working as I expected. Can anyone help me with the correct way to stop the API call before the user submits the search?

To achieve this, you can use the query.setEnabled(false) method provided by Sitecore-Search. This method disables the API calls completely, meaning the API won’t be triggered until you enable it again.
Here’s how to use it step by step:
Disable API calls initially: Use query.setEnabled(false) to stop any unnecessary API calls when the page loads. This ensures the search API won’t make any requests until you're ready.
query: (query) => { 
    query.getRequest();
    query.setEnabled(false);
}

Enable API calls when needed: After the user types a search term and submits it (by pressing Enter or clicking the submit button), you’ll need to enable the API calls again. Do this by calling query.setEnabled(true) before triggering the search.
function onSearchSubmit(searchVal) {
   query.setEnabled(true); // Enable API calls
   onKeyphraseChange({ keyphrase: searchVal }); // Trigger the search again
 }


I tried this and this is working as expected.
Thanks
